# Why use $f: ℝ^m → ℝ^n$ to represent linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

we know in math, there ofen use $f: ℝ^m → ℝ^n$ to represent linear mapping.

and the $ℝ^m$ means $m$-d space and $ℝ^n$ means $n$-d space, does it mean a map from an $m$-d space to an $n$-d space?

In my mind, I think the linear mapping do not change the dimension, check this snapshot:

[image]

The space always is $2$-d space before and after the transformation.

Comment: A linear mapping can change the dimension. Look at the definition. It does not have to, though. You could have $m=n$.

Comment: $f(a,b,c) = a + b + c$ is a linear map from $\Bbb{R}^3$ to $\Bbb{R}^1$.

Comment: $f(a,b,c) = (a,0,b,0,c,0)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb{R}^3$ to $\Bbb{R}^6$.  Admittedly, its image is spanned by exactly three vectors, but the image of $f$ is explicitly $6$-element vectors.

Comment: I think you are confused about the definition of a linear map. What do you think a linear map is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood your snapshot. Note that there are **three** axis arrows on the left part of the picture! The pentagon is "floating" in 3D space. On this pentagon, there is a red line, which is mapped by some linear map $C$ to the blue line, living in 2D space. Hence, this is an example of a map $$C:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2.$$
A linear map in general can be between any two vector spaces, even of different dimension, as long as the map is linear.